# How to make sure the result of lat/lng distance calculation is correct

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude

I'm very novice to GIS systems, and I'm trying to fulfill a requirement. I've created a small program to calculate the distance of a given lat/lng pair, based on [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula).

However, for a city like Tehran which is more like a horizontal rectangle, the width is **way** less than the height.

Since a small city might be regarded as a flat surface comparing to the curvature of Earth, I expect the results to be valid for visual inspection.

[image]

So I also went online to calculate the result, and from [this site](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), the calculation again shows the same numbers, that is, the width is unbelievably smaller than the height.

To get the latitude and longitude, I simply used Google Maps and here are the values:

**leftmost latitude = 35.7267243
rightmost latitude = 35.7442993

topmost longitude = 51.4743653
bottommost longitude = 51.4347113**

Apparently I did something wrong, but I can't really make it work. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your bounding box is wrong, it should roughly be

35.834107; 51.095724
35.561986; 51.605215

Before worrying about the width/height ratio, one would have identified that 2km * 3 km is rather a small size for such a large city...
One degree is about 100 km (see the [order of magnitude table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees)), so, knowing your city, you should have a bounding box with 0.5 to 1 degree in width/height, not 0.05.

Comment: How to get the lat/lng of a place? I right-click on the point, select "what's here", and it gives me the lat/lng. Is it wrong?

Comment: That sounds good. Using you coords, it seems you might have kept the latitude of the most eastern/western point, and the longitude of the northern/southern point (i.e. discarding the wrong coord to establish the bounding box)

Comment: thank you for your help. The key term `bounding box` helped me go find the problem. I had a very embarrassing **deep** misunderstanding of the terms. I thought `latitude` means vertical lines to the equator. Such a shame.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Please consider accepting the answer